# NHibernate.ISession does not contain a definition for Linq

Tags: linq, nhibernate

I'm using NHibernate latest builds but unable to work with linq. I already added `using NHibernate.Linq`, so that's not the issue.

```
using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
{
    var sss = session.Linq<Category>().ToArray(); <-- Error mentioned above.
}
```

Looks like there is no extention method Linq() for ISession, despite the fact thath NHibernate.Linq is in uses list. Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`session.Linq<T>()` is for the contrib provider for NHibernate 2.x

`session.Query<T>()` is for the built-in provider in NHibernate 3.x

Comment: Thanks Mauricio, could you tell me which one is better? In better, I mean more stable, feature rich and better performance. Thanks :)

Comment: @Davita: if you're using NHibernate 3.x, use `session.Query<T>()`. If you're using NHibernate 2.x, use the contrib provider and `session.Linq<T>()`. It's not really a choice.